# PHP GetImageSize reverses Width/Height

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

I have the image attached below with these specifics:
Width: 3024px
Height: 4032px

The getimagesize() function returns the opposite:

```
$size = GetimageSize("test.jpg");
echo "image width: " . $size[0] . ", height: " . $size[1];
```

> image width: 4032, height: 3024

How is this possible?

You can try yourself using the image below.

*** UPDATE ***
Removed image from the post and added a link to zip file (containing the image) because the image works fine after being processed from stack overflow.
[Tinyupload ZIP](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03119960568476211794)

Screenshot of the result:
[image]

Comment: Looks fine on my end. http://i.imgur.com/rRFl9yh.png Are you sure the image isn't rotated?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I fear stack overflow done some image processing after posting it on here. I will try to post a link to download the image from somewhere, And yes, I have checked the image EXIF and orientation is 1, therefore it should be fine

Comment: However it's just a portrait picture taken with my iPhone 6s. Any picture taken seems having the same problem

Comment: Ah, the pictures are viewed correctly because the Exif data are being used. PHP doesn't auto-rotate images, therefore you either need to rotate them before yourself or use PHP to read the Exif data and then rotate the image according to it.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Could you please try with the image inside the ZIP file? It doesn't work with that but it works fine if I use the image processed from stack overflow (I have updated the question with the link)

Comment: Image isn't correctly rotated (upside looks to the left). You have to rotate the image. Just Apple Things.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois what do you mean "upside looks to the left" ? It looks fine to me

Comment: Because Mac rotates the image according to the Exif data. :) Windows doesn't do that, it shows you how it really is, PHP does the same, it doesn't care a bit about Exif orientation.

Comment: Windows or Mac, my only way to understand if an image is correctly oriented is to read the EXIF of the image and read the value "orientation". If that value is 1 that means the image does not need to get rotated.... I swear that from my laptop in the office I could read orientation=1, otherwise the image would have get rotated automatically by my script. I will do some more testing tomorrow, maybe with a windows laptop. but thank you for trying

Comment: I am not sure why the exif orientation states 1 (so it should be correctly rotated) but the reality is, that the top side is left. This was always the case when I had an iOS device myself. I always had to rotate the photos to get the correct orientation. http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

Comment: Thank you, the article is very helpful. If you post an answer below I will accept as a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your image is probably being auto-rotated when you view it. Orientation will play a part in getting the height and width the right way around. This code taken from the [php documentation](http://php.net/exif_read_data) will make sure your image is correctly rotated. There are many other examples in the link to choose from.

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']));
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}
// $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already checked the EXIF and the orientation of the image is 1 therefore the function you posted would not do anything to the image. As soon as I get home I will post a link to download the original image so you can try with it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the link to the image which is having the issues. You can see that it doesn't need rotation

Answer (score -1):

Function `getimagesize()` changes width and height in photos that are landscape orientation (horizontal).
You can use this code:

```
<?php
$img = "test.jpg";
$exif = exif_read_data($img);
if(empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img);
}else{
    list($height, $width, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img);
}
?>
```

But it was fixed automatically in PHP7 and above.